# One jar screws up while Proguard obfuscation, what should I do?

Tags: java, android, proguard, java-bytecode-asm, android-proguard

"asm-4.0.jar", "org.objectweb.asm", if this .jar is included, I get this error, while building:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstMethodRef cannot be cast to com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstInterfaceMethodRef","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstMethodRef cannot be cast to com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstInterfaceMethodRef","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstMethodRef cannot be cast to com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstInterfaceMethodRef","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstMethodRef cannot be cast to com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstInterfaceMethodRef","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"4 errors; aborting","sources":[{}]}
```

Some part from Proguard config:

```
#-libraryjars libs/asm-4.0.jar
-keep class !org.objectweb.asm.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.objectweb.asm.**
```

Full proguard config: http://pastebin.com/mxXK4WvY

> -dontobfuscate

This line makes proguard work, but I need obfuscation.

What should I do? This jar is needed for Kryonet, my whole game is built on it.

Comment: Uhm that "!" looks wrong.

Comment: @rekire but if I remove it, nothing changes, still does not work

Comment: I just reviewed your proguard file. It is the longest one I have ever seen. Are you sure that just that four lines causes the problem? You could check with [jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx) the content of your apk file to check which classes where removed.

Comment: @rekire I think I'm sure, because if I remove this jar, it builds fine. But it is however needed because it's referenced in other jars as I see.

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed it by making it like this:

```
-keep class org.objectweb.asm.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class org.objectweb.asm.** { *; }
-keepclassmembernames class org.objectweb.asm.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.objectweb.asm.**
```